# Many arrays, one listview, one adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

To tell my problem I want to explain on an example

Lets say we have 12 arrays, lets call them List1 to List12 and each of them has different sizes.

I want to show each 3 lists in one screen -I have 4 screens-, so I created an xml for list items and a new Adapter (MyAdapter) which extends ArrayAdapter. I also solved the problem for showing them in one screen by using if statements.

But these 4 screens has different sizes and even if I control `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` problem, the lists has empty rows as I wrote

```
MyAdapter<String> adapter = new MyAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.MyListView,
                List1)
```

Do i have to write 4 adapters as

```
MyAdapter<String> adapter1 = new MyAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.MyListView,
                List1)
MyAdapter<String> adapter2 = new MyAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.MyListView,
                List4)
MyAdapter<String> adapter3 = new MyAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.MyListView,
                List7)
MyAdapter<String> adapter4 = new MyAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.MyListView,
                List10)
```

or is there a simpler solution?

Thank you for your helps!

Myadapter class:

```
public class MyAdapter<String> extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
                String[] listname) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, listname);
        }

        public MyAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, int simpleSpinnerItem,
                String[] listlist) {
            super(mainActivity, simpleSpinnerItem, listlist);
        }



        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

            TextView tv1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
            TextView tv2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textview2);
            TextView tv3 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textview3);
            if (ListID == 1) {
                tv1.setText(List1[position]);
                if (position < List3.length) {
                    tv2.setText(List2[position]);
                    tv3.setText(List3[position]);
                } else if (position < List2.length) {
                    tv2.setText(List4[position]);
                }
            } else if (ListID == 2) {
                       ...
            }

            else
                tv1.setText(list0[position]);
            return row;
        }
    }
```

Length of lists List1 > List2 > List3

Two constructor is just because I have a spinner on screen to go between screens.

ListID is the spinners position.

Padma Kumar's solution worked by adding this. And I used default Adapter for Spinner, which solves my problem.

```
            @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (ListID == 1) {
            return List1.length;
        } else if (ListID == 2) {
            return List4.length;
        } else if (ListID == 3) {
            return List7.length;
        } else if (ListID == 4) {
            return List10.length;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As you know adapter sets the length of lists from the length of array. Lets say List1 has 30 rows, List4 has 25 rows, List7 has 20 rows and List10 has 15 rows, and our screen shows 10 rows.

If I wrote one adapter and put List1 in it, other list tries to show 30 rows too, which is many empty rows. I want to get through this

Comment: can you show your MyAdapter class file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are hardcoding your getcount method make it as below.

```
public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
```

it will return the number of length in your list that you passed.

so that you will never get any empty rows.

Comment: Nope, I didn't use this method. I included MyAdapter to the question

Comment: write gerCount method in your adapter class and get the size by listlist.lenght().

Comment: Oh, thank you. I used something similar and it worked. I just wrote and if statement and checked ListIDs and that worked. But, the spinner caused error now. How can i set the length of spinner using this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you are trying to use different lists on your adapter you should make sure that you call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter after you modify the underlying List object. For example, add something like the code bellow to your custom adapter.

```
public void swapList(List<String> list) {
  mList = list;
  this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Whenever you want to show a different list  on your list view simply call this from your code:

```
mAdapter.swapList(ListX);
```

Comment: I didn't understand what mList should refer to.

Comment: mList is your internal list for the adapter, basically the object that gets assigned List1 from your example code above.